# Merge jquery lines into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to merge these two jquery lines into one:

```
$(".dropdown-menu-and-or li a").click(function(){
    $("#modal-button-and-or:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#modal-button-and-or:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Why do you need these two lines ? They are doing almost the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` or `jQuery` object is returned by *almost* all jQuery functions, so you can "chain" your calls when it concerns the same object (selector).

Which is your need?

So, you can write:

```
$(".dropdown-menu-and-or li a").click(function(){
  $("#modal-button-and-or:first-child").text($(this).text()).val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(".dropdown-menu-and-or li a").click(function(){
    $("#modal-button-and-or:first-child").text($(this).text()).val($(this).text());
});
```